# PDF pages are blank after setting password for existing PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am using iTextSharp (C#) for setting password for a existing PDF. I am able to set the password for the existing pdf but while opening the pdf (after saving) all the pages are completely blank. Please help me with this.

Code Used:

```
private void securePDFFile(string InputFile, string OutputFile)
    {

        using (Stream input = new FileStream(InputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(input);
            using (Stream output = new FileStream(OutputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {

                PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(reader, output, true, null, "secret", PdfWriter.AllowScreenReaders);
            }
        }
    }
```

Regards,
Balaji

Comment: This is usually a problem unrelated to iTextSharp, but caused by wrong I/O. A PDF is a binary file; if you read/save it as an ASCII file, you get the phenomenon you're experiencing. Check the bytes in your file. You'll see that all streams are corrupted due to the way you read or write the bytes.

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie: thanks for your reply and btw I just found quick thing in the Itext sharp documentation that only files that have been created with Itext sharp can be secured using Itext sharp, other files can't be secured and that's reason why its blank.

Comment: Please supply sample files going blank.

Answer (score 0):

I just found quick thing in the Itext sharp documentation that only files that have been created with Itext sharp( the existing pdf's that have been created with Itest Shapr only) can be secured using Itext sharp, other files can't be secured and that's reason why its blank. The best alternative would be PDF sharp which secures all files.

Regards,
 Balaji

Comment: Please tell us where you've found that documentation, because it's obviously wrong.